# Pine Scripts: Find the max Simple Moving Average

Tags: pine-script

In pine scripts, I have several simple moving averages.

```
sma250 = sma(close,250)
sma100 = sma(close,100)
sma50 = sma(close,50)
sma20 = sma(close,20)
sma10 = sma(close,10)
```

I would like to find the max or min of sma250, sma100, sma50m, sma20, sma10

HH=max(sma250, sma100, sma50m, sma20, sma10)
or
LL=min(sma250, sma100, sma50m, sma20, sma10)

All couldn't work.

Could you advise how to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not at my laptop, but I did something similar in the below script:

https://uk.tradingview.com/script/LoAJFXlT-Initial-Balance-Markets-Time-Zones-Overall-Highest-and-Lowest/

Have a look at lines 160 to 187.

Comment: I don't think that works for series. But thanks for your reply